# How to create comma and hyphen separated list of sequential numbers in Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

How do I create a list of numbers, where consequential numbers are reduced to being separated by a hyphen? e.g. I have a column with numbers like

```
1
2
3
5
6
7
8
10
12
```

I want this to be reduced to `1-3,5-8,10,12`. I found this solution for Excel, which includes VBA: https://superuser.com/questions/971161/list-range-of-numbers-in-excel

Of course if this is solvable with just functions (perhaps query could help?), it would be nice!